# fadeOut or setTimeout not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout, fadeout

This script is executed here: [jerusalempetshop.com](http://jerusalempetshop.com/)

The purpose of the script is to replace the Opencart conventional notification with a fadeIn and out notification popup.
It has other parts functioning in a similar way with:

```
$('.success').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
```

The code is:

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

        if (json['redirect']) {
            location = json['redirect'];
        }

        if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' 
            + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" 
            alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
            setTimeout(function() { $('.success').slideDown(500); }, 5000);
            setTimeout(slideOut, 5000);
            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

            $('#minicart .heading').fadeTo(350, 0.1); 
            $('#minicart .heading').fadeTo(350, 1); 
            $('#minicart .heading').fadeTo(350, 0.1); 
            $('#minicart .heading').fadeTo(350, 1); 
            $('#minicart .heading').fadeTo(350, 0.1); 
            $('#minicart .heading').fadeTo(350, 1);
            $('.success').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
        }   
    }
});
}

function slideOut() {
    $('.success').slideDown(500);
}
```

The fadeOut part referred by:

```
$('.success').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
setTimeout(function() { $('.success').slideDown(500); }, 5000);
setTimeout(slideOut, 5000);
```

Is not executed by any of the lines.

Any idea why?
OR
How to fixit.

Thanx.

[The_Script](http://jerusalempetshop.com/catalog/view/theme/ocsh_petshop/popup_ocsh.js)

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Why do you have both `setTimeout(function() { $('.success').slideDown(500); }, 5000);` and `setTimeout(slideOut, 5000);`? These do the same thing. Also, you don't need to `.fadeIn()` because `.slideDown()` makes the element visible.

Comment: I don't read hebrew but looks like it works as expected on chrome `$('.success').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');`

Comment: @nnnnnn: Those were 3 different attempts to get it working.

Comment: @A. Wolf: I am on chrome. Did you click the ADD TO CART button? (sorry, I forgot to mention)

Comment: It looks like ADD TO CART button BUT writes in hebrew. Then the `.success` div appears for 5 sec before fading out. Maybe you just have a cache issue, have you clear it?

Comment: ok. ENGLISH WEBSITE: On home page hover on a product-> click 'ADD TO CART'=popup fadeOut after 5secs. If you click on product and go to product page and then click 'ADD TO CART'=popup does NOT fadeOut .

Comment: Thank you everyone :-) as I did not resolve this specific issue I have found a work around: I added the  $('.success').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
to the product page itself and it works.